# Loading language package fails

Tags: errors, languages

trying to use finnish language package. But this code only lets me use english. I get "Package babel Error: You haven't loaded the language english yet." error if i try to change

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
```

to

```
 \usepackage[finnish]{babel}
```

my code currently ( I use a template..)

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, finnish,fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl} % A4 paper and 11pt font size

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
\usepackage{fourier} % Use the Adobe Utopia font for the document - comment this line to         return to the LaTeX default
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage[finnish]{babel}
% English language/hyphenation
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm} % Math packages


\usepackage{lipsum} % Used for inserting dummy 'Lorem ipsum' text into the template

\usepackage{sectsty} % Allows customizing section commands
\allsectionsfont{\centering \normalfont\scshape} % Make all sections centered, the     default font and small caps

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Custom headers and footers
\pagestyle{fancyplain} % Makes all pages in the document conform to the custom headers   and footers
\fancyhead{} % No page header - if you want one, create it in the same way as the footers below
\fancyfoot[L]{} % Empty left footer
\fancyfoot[C]{} % Empty center footer
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage} % Page numbering for right footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Remove header underlines
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % Remove footer underlines
\setlength{\headheight}{13.6pt} % Customize the height of the header

\numberwithin{equation}{section} % Number equations within sections (i.e. 1.1, 1.2, 2.1,   2.2 instead of 1, 2, 3, 4)
\numberwithin{figure}{section} % Number figures within sections (i.e. 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2 instead of 1, 2, 3, 4)
\numberwithin{table}{section} % Number tables within sections (i.e. 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2 instead of 1, 2, 3, 4)

\setlength\parindent{0pt} % Removes all indentation from paragraphs - comment this line for an assignment with lots of text
```

Comment: When you switch languages you get errors. Ignore them, they will disappear on the next run. Or delete the auxiliary files.

Comment: It won't run my code thru if i "%" the english language and use the usepackage[finnish]{babel} :(

Comment: On that basis, this is a duplicate of a similar question.